# Active class is being added after 2-3 seconds delay in bxslider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have a bxslider and am adding active class to the active slide but i noticed that Active class is being added to the slide after 2-3 seconds delay. Here is my code

```
jQuery('.banner_slider').bxSlider({
infiniteLoop: true,
hideControlOnEnd: true,
adaptiveHeight : true,
useCSS: false,
speed: 2000,
pause: 8000,
mode: 'fade',
controls:false,
autoDelay: 2800,
onSliderLoad: function(){
    jQuery('.banner_slider .slide_banner').eq(0).addClass('active-slide');
    jQuery("img.firstanimatedphone").animate({ opacity: 1},2000);
    jQuery("img.firstanimatedphone").addClass('slideInRight');
    elementsmoving(); 
},
onSlideAfter: function (currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
    jQuery('.active-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
    jQuery('.banner_slider .slide_banner').eq(currentSlideHtmlObject).addClass('active-slide');
    jQuery("img.firstanimatedphone").animate({ opacity: 1},2000);
    jQuery("img.firstanimatedphone").addClass('slideInRight');
},
auto: false  
});
```

Could you help me to figure out why the class .active-slide is being added after 2-3 seconds delay?

Comment: can you please provide fiddle for that?

Comment: maybe due to this `autoDelay: 2800`

Comment: Seems no i removed that but again 2-3 seconds delay for adding the active slide @Raviteja

Comment: I found it was a setting of `speed: 2000,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heey i found.It was from a setting called

```
speed: 2000,
```